# Every hindu is associated to Kuldevi and Kuldev. What is the purpose of it?

Tags: gods, worship, ancestry

Every person in Hindu community is linked to Kuldevi and Kuldev. Everyone in Hinduism have Kuldevi and Kuldev.

1. What is the purpose of it?
2. What are the rituals for Kuldevi and Kuldev?
3. If I don't know my Kuldev and Kuldevi, then how to find it?
4. Why every Hindu is associated to Kuldevi and Kuldev?

Comment: Not every....!!

Comment: @Rishabh Then which hindu are associated with Kuldev and Kuldevi.

Comment: Those Hindus who wants to associate :)

Comment: @Rishabh How can you say hindu dont have kuldevi

Answer (score 1):

If you are able to trace back your Poorvaj, you will come to know that at one point of time they originated from any Rishi who himself originated from any Devta. In this way the Devta with whom your DNA matches, is your Kuldevta.

In case you don't know Kuldevta/Kuldevi, you can simply worship them with below mantras:

```
|| ॐ श्री कुलदेवताभ्यो नमः ||

|| ॐ श्री कुलदेव्यै नमः ||
```

I do have a more elaborate ritual which can be done once a month.

When Kuldevta and Kuldevi are not known, you can offer separate prasadam in their name to your deity.

Since Kuldevta and Kuldevi have a direct link with your DNA, they are considered more close to you as compared to other Devtas. In this way they are also your family's first line of defense against negative energies.

Regular worship and Homa of Kuldevta creates a shield around your family. These days people don't worship Kuldevta and don't know even. Therefore, the shield which protects the family weakens over time.

Comment: **I do have a more elaborate ritual which can be done once a month.** What r those rituals

Comment: I can mail you the PDF. Is there chat option in StackExchange?

Comment: Yes there is chat option but it is available after some comments. my email id is praveengaikwad15@gmail.com. I am waiting for the email.

Comment: Ok I will mail today.

Comment: hey can you please share in public please, a link? we want that info at hindumediawiki.com